# How can I repeat image 5 times using css?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to repeat the  image 'n times' using css?

Comment: you mean just have it dynamically generate html tags the image n times in the document? no.... gotta use javascript / jquery

Comment: please give proper explanation and with proper code.Can u please tell me What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the image as a background for an element, and set the size of the element so that the image is repeated exactly five times.

Example:

```
div {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100);
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ANbHr/

Answer (score 0):

In CSS2.1, the background-repeat property had four options: no-repeat, repeat, repeat-x and repeat-y. CSS3 introduces two new options: space and round.